# Meteor Deployment - how upgrade application

Tags: javascript, meteor

I implemented the applications on my own server, using the information contained under the link: https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-a-slack-clone-in-meteor-js-part-5-deployment

I want to ask how update the production version of the application ( adding more packages from the page https://atmospherejs.com/ and changing the code in the same application).

Comment: The post you linked to describes multiple methods of deployment. Which one did you use?

Comment: 1.nginx as a reverse proxy web server which passes requests to our application; 
2.mongodb; 
3.pm2 – A production process manager that keeps an eye on our application, and restart it if it crashes.

Comment: You'll need to replace the files and restart the pm2 job by running `pm2 restart all`.

Comment: That's what I was doing, but after starting the application server have a problem with nginx "502 Bad Gateway"